# Why do I get the error "Unary Operator Expected" when constructing this simple if else statement?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, command-line

I'm   making a program, lab5, to test if the argument is a directory or a file. when I run the program with "bash lab5", I get "unary operator expected on line 3 and 5" What is the problem? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

if test "$1" -d
then
    echo "This is a directory"
elif test "$1" -f
then 
    echo "This is a file"
else
    echo "This is neither a file or a directory"
```

fi

Comment: The correct syntax is `if test -d "$1"` etc.  `man test` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` does not have postfix operators, only prefix and infix operators. `-f` and `-d` are both prefix operators, meaning they come *before* the argument you want to test.

```
if test -d "$1"
then
    echo "This is a directory"
elif test -f "$1"
then 
    echo "This is a file"
else
    echo "This is neither a file or a directory"
fi
```

The exact error occurs because the shell sees something like `test foo -d`, and notes that `test` received exactly two arguments. With two arguments, it proceeds as follows:

1. If the first argument is `!`, it just checks if the second argument is empty or not.
2. Otherwise, the first argument *must* be a unary operator, which `foo` is not.